# Android database solution

Tags: android, database

I am currently developing an application on Android that will need to read and write to a database. The problem is each person using the application will need to be reading the same data and so if one person adds data, that is only available to their specific installation of the app.

What I need is a solution where everyone is reading and writing from the same database, perhaps a database on the web that everyone can connect to,

So what I am asking is what is the best approach/API's to a single database for everyone?

Comment: Are you talking about all users on a device or global on differnt devices?

Comment: Global on different devices, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you need for that seanrio at least a webspace with e.g. php support (if the sqlite plugin is aviable). In general I would suggest to use a real SQL or nonSQL server (depending on what you want to achive). From my experiance I would suggest to use mysql it is very common on the web.

For my explanation I'll take PHP and MySQL as example.

### Preparation

At first make sure that your server has the right plugins installed. You can check this with a one line php script:

```
<?php php_info(); ?>
```

#### Database access

There you should look for a secion [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/mysqli) or better look for [`PDO`](http://php.net/pdo). Please note if you find a secion `mysql` please don't use that. They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). You should learn how to use [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi). If you are not sure to decide what to use read [this article](http://php.net/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

A quick note why you should not use not use SQLite on the server side: This database is file based and does not have a support for multiple users at once. By the way this is no problem on the client side (Android) there is only one user at once.

### Designing your architecture

Before you start make sure that have a basic idea how many users you will get. This is critical important if you have let's say 10k users any each request will take 10 seconds your customers won't use your app.

Read about [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) for a efficency data storage in some rare cases also [denormalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) is good to know for high performance usecases.

### Secutiry

You should know how to secure the data of your users here in special about how to secure the user passwords which are very important to protect your users in case that your site get's been hacked. All password must not been stored as plain text! Instead store a so called hash of them together with an random salt. As an example let's take the passwort "12345678" (which is by the way most common) generate a random hash on linux systems with `/dev/urandom` see also [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/26206/should-i-use-urandom-or-openssl-random-pseudo-bytes). If you don't want to care about user passwords you could also use a [Google+ Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/+/features/sign-in), this is a quiet cool feature but this is also very complex.

In general you should also transphere all data encrypted by ssl but this is quiet expensive. Also if there are some ways to get free certificases like [CAcert](http://cacert.org) or [StartSSL](http://startssl.com).

If you use prepared statements as recommended above you don't need to care about [(blind) SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) but it is also helpful to know that this exists.

### Transmissions

I recomment to implement a [REST API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST) together with the [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) format for transmitting data. For encoding the data you can use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/function.json-encode.php) and on Android the classes [`JSONObject`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html). If you also want that the data are automatically converted to classes you could use [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).